# Angular Js is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

angular js not displaying anything even like simple expressions. i am tying to execute below code but no hope. can anyone help me out.

below code is for view to display.

```html
`<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../Scripts/angularsample.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="spiceApp">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="SpicyController">
            <p> lets try some code by using service </p>
            <input ng-init="message='Girish'" ng-model="message" />
            <button ng-click="notify(message);">Notify{{1+2}}</button>
            <p>alert will display only by clicking three times.</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="List">
            <button ng-click="bringList()">getList</button>
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="app in appslist">
                    <td>
                        {{app.Name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

js code

```js
var myApp = angular.module('spiceApp', []);

myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService', , function ($scope, $http, userService) {

  //below code is using sservice 
    $scope.notify = function (msg) {
        userService(msg);
    };
    
}]);


myApp.controller('List', ['$scope', 'getList', function ($scope, getList) {
    $scope.bringList = function () {
        getList.getAppsList().then(function (list) {
            $scope.appslist = list;
        });
    };

}]);

myApp.factory('getList', ['$http',function ($http) {
    //this code for getting list from controller.
    return getList.getAppsList=function(){
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Home/GetAppsList'
        })
    .success(function (response) {
       return response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    }
}]);

myApp.factory('userService', ['$window', function (win) {
    var msgs = [];
    return function (msg) {
        msgs.push(msg);
        if (msgs.length == 3) {
            win.alert(msgs.join('\n'));
            msgs = [];
        }
    };

}]);`
```

please tell me where i am wrong. nothing is working. expression is displaying like {{1+2}} in the ouptut.

Comment: Do you have errors in the console ?

Comment: now i am getting error in console is:

Comment: ReferenceError: getList is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (angularsample.js:36)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4708)
    at Object.$get (angular.js:4547)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4708)
    at angular.js:4507
    at d (angular.js:4654)
    at e (angular.js:4678)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4700)
    at P.instance (angular.js:10177)
    at n (angular.js:9096)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13642

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService', , function
```

with the 2 comas so the dependancies are messed up.

Comment: yeah , now template is working fine . but not able to return the list from service to controller

Comment: can you have a look at it please

Answer (score 0):

i tried in different way with same view but i modified the js file now it's working fine.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('spiceApp', []);

myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService',function ($scope, $http, userService) {

  //below code is using sservice 
    $scope.notify = function (msg) {
        userService(msg);
    };
    
}]);

myApp.factory('userService', ['$window', function (win) {
    var msgs = [];
    return function (msg) {
        msgs.push(msg);
        if (msgs.length == 3) {
            win.alert(msgs.join('\n'));
            msgs = [];
        }
    };

}]);


myApp.controller('List', ['$scope', 'getList', function ($scope, getList) {
    
    $scope.bringList = function () {
        getList.getAppsList.then(function (data) {
            $scope.appslist = data;
        });

    };

}]);

var getList = angular.module("spiceApp").factory("getList", ['$http', function ($http, getList) {
    return {
        getAppsList: (function (response) {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'GetAppsList'
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("coming from servicejs", response.data);
                //return data when promise resolved
                //that would help you to continue promise chain.
                return response.data;
            });
        })()
    };
    return getList;
}]);
```